# How can I set individual marker size on stock marker series in Anychart?

Tags: anychart

How can I set individual marker size on STOCK MARKER series? It works fine on basic MARKER series: https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Marker_Chart#individual_points

Answer (score 1):

The Stock chart implements a special mode that supports individual point settings. Usually, it is required for coloring but it also supports marker sizing too.
Here is [the sample](https://playground.anychart.com/kb1UbAmi).
Pay attention to the chart data and line 19. The `true` argument is required to enable this mode.